# Deploying azure application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, azure, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the source code of a windows azure project. If I uncomment the following line, the web project in the solution works fine:

```
<!-- add key="MongoDB.ConnectionString" value="mongodb://nameofx.cloudapp.net:27293" / -->
```

I signed up a new trial account for windows azure and now I want to deploy the cloud service to my new account. What parts of Service Configuration do I have to update and what do I have to do in windows azure portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/)?

Here is the screen shot of my cloud project of my solution.

[image]

After I created a cloud service in management panel and try to upload my package, I get the following error:

> The certificate with thumbprint 919691b3c381b92cc314c316ffcc12903967673e was not found.

Here is the **Certificates** part of configuration:

```
<Certificates>
    <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="919691B3C381B92CC314C316FFCC12903967673E" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    <Certificate name="Test.InvestorAccountEncryption" thumbprint="6053B67BC5BECEFE4E2090B1C86F592D4358B3A2" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    <Certificate name="test.aaa.com" thumbprint="C3B019A7C220CF155C1275E7F3209A94378E2384" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    <Certificate name="Test" thumbprint="673398470B32371B06116F7A0B06046EDAC2BF57" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If your certificate is for example a Https certificate, you will have to upload it manually via the management portal. Select your 'cloud service' go to 'certificates' and press upload. Navigate to your certificate and enter the password. After that press OK and your certificate will be uploaded. Once the certificate has been uploaded and installed, uploading your package should work no longer give that error!

Comment: Share the `Certificates` section you have from the `cscfg` file.

Comment: I added the Certificates part @SliverNinja

Comment: When uploading a package via the Management portal you will have to upload your certificates manually. You most likely have to do that for every certificate you added.

Comment: I uploaded my certificate manually, but the deployment still gives the same error. @Xciles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thumbprint it is complaining about is your **RDP Connection** (*Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption*). By default, the Azure SDK will use the same **Windows Azure Tools** certificate that is used to authenticate during publishing.

You need to configure your RDP (*Remote Desktop*) Certificate. To configure, just right click on your **Azure Project** within Visual Studio and select **Configure Remote Desktop...**. This will open a prompt and allow you to setup your authentication certificate properly for RDP.

If you don't publish direct from Visual Studio, then you won't have the **Windows Azure Tools** certificate and [you will need to create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg465712.aspx) and [upload it via the portal role certificates section](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-cloud-service/#uploadcertificate). It's [much easier to just publish directly from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh535756.aspx).

Once your role instance is **Running**, you can [manage the RDP Certificate and Login from within the Management Portal by using the Configure->Remote action](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/#remoteaccess).